# Unable to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I am trying to run my rails server using the following command:

```
   rails s
```

It throws the following error:

> /Users/babaloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/airbrake-ruby- 
>     4.2.1/lib/airbrake-ruby/tdigest.rb:1:in `require':    dlopen(/Users/babaloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rbtree3- 
>     0.5.0/rbtree.bundle, 9):    Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.2.5.dylib    (LoadError)
>
> Referenced from: /Users/babaloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rbtree3- 
>     0.5.0/rbtree.bundle

Please help me how to solve this problem, Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you installed ruby via brew? You can run `brew doctor` to check for issue with ruby. After confirming issue, you can relink ruby with `brew link --overwrite ruby`

Comment: thanks for reply. No i use RVM to install any ruby and i tried this command but no use

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the airbrake gem to see if the server starts? Also try removing RVM with 'rvm implode' ande see if you have another ruby/gem installed that might be causing a problem. If you do, delete that version and reinstall a clean ruby with rvm.

Comment: I am using mac os. I had to reinstall rails and rvm too. But after installing and I am able to run my server now but i am unable to bundle in jruby getting zsh: command not found: bundle errors.